# bitcoind rpc command timeout

Tags: timeout, bitcoind

I'm running bitcoind v0.17
after booting it and running it for a little while, it eventually timeouts ALL rpc command requests. If I use the CLI as well, it also times out.

This is what happens:

https://gyazo.com/f97ecb3358761b3e3e99cd57535b9bf5

I checked the debug.log and there's nothing that I can see that explains what's happening.
Tail of debug log:

```
==> .bitcoin/debug.log <==
2022-02-06T14:03:23Z [default wallet] Fee Calculation: Fee:520 Bytes:166 Needed:520 Tgt:6 (requested 6) Reason:"Conservative Double Target longer horizon" Decay 0.99520: Estimation: (2292.02 - 6081.41) 95.39% 52810.8/(53399.3 0 mem 1963.4 out) Fail: (2182.87 - 2292.02) 90.93% 865.1/(874.1 0 mem 77.4 out)
2022-02-06T14:03:23Z [default wallet] keypool keep 3599
2022-02-06T14:03:25Z [default wallet] keypool added 1 keys (1 internal), size=2000 (1000 internal)
2022-02-06T14:23:22Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
2022-02-06T14:23:23Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
2022-02-06T14:23:23Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
2022-02-06T14:23:24Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
2022-02-06T14:23:25Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
2022-02-06T14:23:25Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
2022-02-06T14:23:26Z socket sending timeout: 1201s
```

Any ideas as to how I can go about debugging this?